# PL/SQL: Invalid Number error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a procedure for which I collect data by repeatedly running the following query.

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,
       COUNT(src1) CNT1,
       COUNT(src2) CNT2 
FROM   (
  SELECT a.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,
         1 src1,
         TO_NUMBER(NULL) src2 
  FROM   (
    SELECT DECODE(
             L,
             1, IP_ADDRESS,
             DECODE(
               L,
               2, IP_SUBNET_MASK,
               DECODE(
                 L,
                 3, IP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY
               )
             )
           ) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 
    FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL X CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ), 
           REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES 
    WHERE  LIP_IPT_NAME = 'CE' 
    AND    IP_LNT_ID IN ( 
             SELECT LNT_ID 
             FROM REUT_LOAD_NTN 
             WHERE LNT_ID IN ( 
               SELECT RLPN.LPN_LNT_ID 
               FROM REUT_LOAD_PI_NTN RLPN 
               WHERE LPN_LPI_ID IN ( 
                 SELECT RLPI.LPI_ID 
                 FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI 
                 WHERE RLPI.LPI_DATE_ADDED IN ( 
                   SELECT MAX(RLPI2.LPI_DATE_ADDED) 
                   FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI2 
                   WHERE RLPI2.PI_JOB_ID = P_ORDER_ID 
                 ) 
               ) 
             ) 
             AND IP_CEASE_DATE IS NULL 
             AND LNT_SERVICE_INSTANCE = 'PRIMARY' 
           )
```

It is running fine in SQL developer but when executing it as a procedure, I am getting INVALID NUMBER ERROR (ORA-01722: invalid number) at

`AND IP_LNT_ID IN ( 
                        SELECT LNT_ID`, in the code.
Can I get any help?

Comment: have you checked, your columns type and length of IP_LNT_ID and LNT_ID

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. You're comparing a number to another type of value.

Example:

```
SELECT 'x'
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 'a'
               FROM DUAL)
```

This means that `IP_LNT_ID`, `LNT_ID`, `LPN_LNT_ID` and `LPI_ID` have to be `NUMBER`. And `LPI_DATE_ADDED` and `LPI_DATE_ADDED` should both be date or timestamp.

If this is not possible you could compare everything as `char`:

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, COUNT(src1) CNT1, COUNT(src2) CNT2 
        FROM (SELECT a.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, 1 src1, TO_NUMBER(NULL) src2 
            FROM (SELECT 
                    DECODE(L,1,IP_ADDRESS,DECODE(L,2,IP_SUBNET_MASK,DECODE(L,3,IP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY) ) ) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 
                    FROM 
                    ( 
                        SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL X CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
                    ), 
                    REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES 
                    WHERE LIP_IPT_NAME = 'CE' 
                    AND to_char(IP_LNT_ID) IN ( 
                        SELECT LNT_ID 
                        FROM REUT_LOAD_NTN 
                        WHERE to_char(LNT_ID) IN ( 
                                SELECT RLPN.LPN_LNT_ID 
                                FROM REUT_LOAD_PI_NTN RLPN 
                                WHERE to_char(LPN_LPI_ID) IN ( 
                                    SELECT RLPI.LPI_ID 
                                    FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI 
                                    WHERE to_char(RLPI.LPI_DATE_ADDED) IN ( 
                                        SELECT MAX(RLPI2.LPI_DATE_ADDED) 
                                        FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI2 
                                        WHERE RLPI2.PI_JOB_ID = P_ORDER_ID 
                                    ) 
                            ) 
                    ) 
                    AND IP_CEASE_DATE IS NULL 
                    AND LNT_SERVICE_INSTANCE = 'PRIMARY' 
            )
```

But this should be avoided on any cost. Unfortunately some times we have to cheat a little from time to time to work with our existing infrasructure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure:

```
REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES.IP_LNT_ID
```

and

```
REUT_LOAD_NTN.LNT_ID
```

Have the same data type or cast/convert one or other so that they have the same data type.

There are multiple other issues:

1. You have aggregated and non-aggregated values:

   ```
   SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,
          COUNT(src1) CNT1,
          COUNT(src2) CNT2 
   FROM   ( ... )
   ```

   Without a `GROUP BY` clause.
2. `src2` is `TO_NUMBER(NULL)` which is just `NULL` and `COUNT(NULL)` will always be `0` so your query is:

   ```
   SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,
          COUNT(src1) CNT1,
          0 CNT2
   ...
   ```
3. This code:

   ```
   SELECT DECODE(
            L,
            1, IP_ADDRESS,
            DECODE(
              L,
              2, IP_SUBNET_MASK,
              DECODE(
                L,
                3, IP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY
              )
            )
          ) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 
   FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL X CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ), 
          REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES
   ```

   Can be rewritten as:

   ```
   SELECT DECODE(
            L,
            1, IP_ADDRESS,
            2, IP_SUBNET_MASK,
            3, IP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY
          ) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 
   FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL X CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ), 
          REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES
   ```

   Or, without the join as:

   ```
   SELECT attribute_value
   FROM   REUT_LOAD_IP_ADDRESSES
   UNPIVOT ( attribute_value FOR L IN (
     IP_ADDRESS         AS 1,
     IP_SUBNET_MASK     AS 2,
     IP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY AS 3
   ) )
   ```
4. The innermost query:

   ```
   SELECT RLPI.LPI_ID 
   FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI 
   WHERE RLPI.LPI_DATE_ADDED IN ( 
     SELECT MAX(RLPI2.LPI_DATE_ADDED) 
     FROM REUT_LOAD_PAC_INS RLPI2 
     WHERE RLPI2.PI_JOB_ID = P_ORDER_ID 
   )
   ```

   The inner query is restricted to have `RLPI2.PI_JOB_ID = P_ORDER_ID` but there is no correlation between the outer query so you can retrieve results that do not match `P_ORDER_ID` but just happen to have the same date as a matching row.